# Is is possible to implement SSO with SAML 2.0 without spring boot

Tags: saml-2.0

I need to implement SSO for a legacy application built in java 1.6 and spring framework 3.1.2 using SAML2.0.  I have already implemented SSO using SAML2.0 with the latest spring-boot. Is it possible to implement SSO without using springboot.

Answer (score 0):

Spring is essentially a SAML client-side library.

There are [others](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43).

In the Java world, OpenSAML is a possible option.